# Selecionar múltiplos arquivos

Tags: javascript, html, jade

Preciso selecionar em média 1500 até 3000 arquivos, no entanto, apenas 1200 estão sendo selecionados com o input abaixo.

Alguém tem ideia do motivo?

```
input class="form-control", type="file", accept="text/xml", name="file", id="file", multiple onchange="handleFileSelect(event)"
```

Comment: Queres dizer que esse input deverá selecionar 3000 ficheiros? podes explicar mais sobre a aplicação que estás a fazer?

Comment: Isso mesmo, preciso selecionar inicialmente 2000 ficheiros, mas seleciona no máximo 1200. Conforme este exemplo:http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/zy3h7erx/.    Se eu colocar os 2000 arquivos que preciso fazer upload, não irá selecionar.